# Raw query not working after changing to Laravel syntax

Tags: laravel

I have converted this query into Laravel syntax, but unfortunately, there is no output in vardump, although it is working in the raw syntax. I think something is wrong in the syntax :

SQL syntax (working fine):

```
$word_rec = DB::select( DB::raw("
select distinct
pa.alias 
,p.name_full_formatted
, o.ordered_as_mnemonic 
, c3.event_tag    RET
, c2.event_tag   QTY
, c1.event_tag   CHK

from

CLINICAL_EVENT   C1   
, orders  o
, encounter  e
, person  p
, person_alias  pa
, CLINICAL_EVENT   C2  
, CLINICAL_EVENT   C3  


 where e.person_id = o.person_id
 and p.person_id = o.person_id
 and pa.person_id = p.person_id
and pa.person_alias_type_cd = 10
 and o.order_id = c2.order_id and c2.task_assay_cd = 2622303965
 and o.order_id = c3.order_id and c3.task_assay_cd = 2622303953
 and c1.encntr_id = o.encntr_id and c1.task_assay_cd = 2622303989
")
 );
```

Laravel syntax (not working):

```
$word_rec = DB::table('orders as o')
    ->join('encounter as e', 'e.person_id', '=', 'o.person_id')
    ->join('person as p', 'p.person_id', '=', 'o.person_id')
    ->join('person_alias as pa', 'pa.person_id', '=', 'p.person_id')
    ->join('clinical_event as c2', 'c2.order_id', '=', 'o.order_id')
    ->join('clinical_event as c3', 'c3.order_id', '=', 'o.order_id')
    ->join('clinical_event as c1', 'c1.encntr_id', '=', 'o.encntr_id')
    ->where('pa.person_alias_type_cd' , '=' , 10)
    ->where('c2.task_assay_cd' , '=' , 2622303965)
    ->where('c3.task_assay_cd' , '=', 2622303953)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can use toSql() method instead of get() to get an idea of raw sql Laravel converts into. Then you can compare two queries and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel better way to use relationships, like this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships.

Define models and correct funtions for relation (one-to-one, one-to-many, ...) than use Model::with().